# What is the expectation of ${{\log }_{2}}X$ if $X>0$ and $X\sim Poisson\left( \lambda \right)$?

Tags: logarithms, expected-value, poisson-distribution

Assume that $X$ is a random variable following Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda $. Note that $X$ is non-negative, i.e., $X>0$. I want to calculate the expectation of ${{\log }_{2}}X$.  What I have done is as follows:
\begin{align}
   \mathbb{E}\left\{ {{\log }_{2}}X \right\}&=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{{{\log }_{2}}k\frac{{{\lambda }^{k}}}{k!}{{e}^{-\lambda }}} \\ 
 & =\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }{{{\log }_{2}}\left( k+1 \right)\frac{{{\lambda }^{k+1}}}{\left( k+1 \right)!}{{e}^{-\lambda }}} \\ 
 & =\lambda \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\log }_{2}}\left( k+1 \right)}{k+1}\frac{{{\lambda }^{k}}}{k!}{{e}^{-\lambda }}} \\ 
 & =\lambda \mathbb{E}\left\{ \frac{{{\log }_{2}}\left( Y+1 \right)}{Y+1} \right\}  
\end{align}

The problem of calculating the expectation of ${{\log }_{2}}X$ has been converted to calculating the expectation of $\frac{{{\log }_{2}}\left( Y+1 \right)}{Y+1}$ with $Y\sim Poisson\left( \lambda  \right)$. The variable $Y$ follows a standard Poisson distribution of mean $\lambda $ without any restriction.

How can I make a further analysis to get the **approximation** of the expectation or the **upper bound** or **lower bound** of $\mathbb{E}\left\{ \frac{{{\log }_{2}}\left( Y+1 \right)}{Y+1} \right\}$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Another method to get the upper bound with Jensen's inequality is as follows:
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}\left\{ {{\log }_{2}}X \right\}& \le {{\log }_{2}}\left( \mathbb{E}\left\{ X \right\} \right) \\ 
 & ={{\log }_{2}}\left( \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{k\frac{{{\lambda }^{k}}}{k!}{{e}^{-\lambda }}} \right) \\ 
 & ={{\log }_{2}} \lambda  
\end{align}

Comment: You keep contradicting yourself. Is $X$ Poisson-distributed, or is it $Y+1$ with $Y$ Poisson-distributed? Do you want the mean of a Poisson variable's logarithm (trivially $-\infty$ as this value has positive probability), the mean of the logarithm of one more than a Poisson variable, or the mean of $\frac{\log_2(Y+1)}{Y+1}$ with $Y\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$?

Comment: In my opinion, for a standard Poisson distribution, the variable values can be taken from $0,1,2,\cdots$. But here $X$ follows a non-standard Poisson, because $X>0$. In order to get $\mathbb{E}\left\{ {{\log }_{2}}X \right\}$, I have introduced the variable $Y$ following a standard Poisson distribution, i.e., its values can be taken from $0,1,2,\cdots$. Calculating  $\mathbb{E}\left\{ {{\log }_{2}}X \right\}$ with $X>0, X\sim Poisson\left(\lambda  \right)$  and $\mathbb{E}\left\{ \frac{{{\log }_{2}}\left(Y+1 \right)}{Y+1} \right\}$ with $Y\sim Poisson\left( \lambda  \right)$  are equivalent.

Comment: So are you defining $X=(Y+1)^{1/(Y+1)}$? Why?

Comment: According to the above derivation, due to $\mathbb{E}\left\{ {{\log }_{2}}X \right\}=\lambda \mathbb{E}\left\{ \frac{{{\log }_{2}}\left( Y+1 \right)}{Y+1} \right\}$, we have $X\ne {{\left( Y+1 \right)}^{{1}/{\left( Y+1 \right)}\;}}$.

Comment: But it makes no sense. By just skipping $k=0$, you've obtained probabilities for $X$ that only sum to $1-e^{-\lambda}$, not $1$. Perhaps you meant $X-1\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$, so $\Bbb Ef(X)=\sum_{k=1}f(k)e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$.

Comment: When $X=0$, ${{\log }_{2}}\left( X \right)$ is meaningless. I want to get the expectation of  $\mathbb{E}\left\{ {{\log }_{2}}X \right\}$ instead of $\mathbb{E}\left\{ X \right\}$.

Comment: *I know* you don't want $\Bbb EX$. Do you agree with my previous comment's inference that you want $\Bbb E\log_2(Y+1)$ with $Y\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$?

Comment: I want $\mathbb{E}\left\{ \frac{{{\log }_{2}}\left( Y+1 \right)}{Y+1} \right\}$ instead of $\mathbb{E}\left\{ {{\log }_{2}}\left( Y+1 \right) \right\}$ with $Y\sim Poisson\left( \lambda  \right)$.